# show and hide angular 2

Tags: angular, show-hide

Having issue with showing boolean element. If i'm trying to set show hide element in html it works like:

```
<p class="post-more-text" (click)="model.isTextVisible = !model.isTextVisible;">{{model.moreOrLessValue}}</p>
```

If I set a function in component, the element isn't hiding

```
<p *ngIf="isTextVisible">
    {{model?.morePostText}}
</p>

<p class="post-more-text" (click)="onMoreInfoClick(model)">{{model.moreOrLessValue}}</p>
```

and component:

```
onMoreInfoClick(model) {
    model.isTextVisible = !model.isTextVisible;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *[hidden]* attribute is not recommended for Angular2. Better use *ngIf* condition. in this way:

```
<p *ngIf="model.isTextVisible">
    {{model?.morePostText}}
</p>
```

More you can read [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)

---

edited: Additionaly, I think that you forget parent of your *isTextVisible* attribute. Should it look like: `*ngIf="model.isTextVisible"` ??

Comment: sorry, forgot to change to ngIf. i tried with hidden with hope it will works :)

Comment: it helped? I am curious if the problem was [hidden] attr or that you forget "model." before isTextVisible

Comment: yes it helped, the solution was with forgot to add model...)